# Minicart: failed to load template

Tags: template, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I'm using a custom template and having an issue with the minicart rendering.
The minicart pop-up renders, but does not gather any data with 2 errors in the console.
[image]

So the popup does open when you click on it, but due to the errors above, only part of the contents are being loaded:

[image]

More info about the environment:

- Custom theme does not overwrite any Catalog or checkout templates
- The theme is based upon Luma theme and the minicart does work as expected when activating the Luma theme.
- Tried resetting cache, compiling and regenerating multiple times
- I've also tried copying the template files from the base folders to my theme, but the same issue remains
- The minicart template in the layout file is a straight up copy from the base magento files

  ```
  <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
               <arguments>
                   <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                       <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                               </item>
                               <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                   <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                       </item>
                                       <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                               <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                   <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                               </item>
                                           </item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                                   <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                                   <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                       <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                       <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                           <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                       </item>
                                   </item>
                               </item>
                           </item>
                       </item>
                   </argument>
               </arguments>
               <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
           </block>`
  ```

Could it be that I am missing or filtering out any Javascript loading in the custom theme?
The theme I'm using is built upon [Magento2-sass-tailwind-theme](https://github.com/NavaneethVijay/magento2-sass-tailwindcss-theme) with mostly upgrades to styles.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your theme minicart folder, It has `.html` files.

```
Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/
```

Match your theme file with vendor files.

The issue seems to be in `.html` files inside the theme having some HTML tags miss match

Comment: There are no template files inside the Magento_Checkout folder in my theme. I have tried placing the base templates from the Magento source in my theme, but the result stays the same.

Comment: Check in custom module and run this command : rm -rf generated/* var/cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/frontend/*

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the error message:

> Message: this.itemRenderer is undefined.
> getItemRenderer@yourMagentoDomain/.../MagentoCheckout/js/view/minicart.js:131:33

It is called in line 131 in **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js**

```
getItemRenderer: function (productType) {
    return this.itemRenderer[productType] || 'defaultRenderer';
},
```

`itemRenderer` is the config declared in **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml**.
Check your custom themes, custom modules, third-party modules, and third-party theme to ensure nothing overrides `minicart_content` (the parent of `itemRenderer`) component and removed the `itemRenderer` config or something similar.

You can leverage the **Knockoutjs context debugger** browser extension to debug this issue: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof

More information about it: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/debug/

**Update**: I've checked your previous post, which indicated you missed the config for `itemRenderer`. So, to resolve your issue, add this config to "minicart_content" in your xml file (as you mentioned, it is default.xml?):

```
<argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="itemRenderer" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                    <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                    <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">defaultRenderer</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            ...
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>
```